Split a String as CLI args
I have a string that resembles os.Arg[1:] prior to being exploded. I need to explode this string as normal cli arguments would be so I can pass it to flag.FlagSet.Parse (more specifically, pflag.FlagSet.Parse).

The obvious first idea is to strings.Split() the string. However, this does not respect quotation, causing only the first element to treated as the value and the rest as bare arguments.
ex: --cron="* * * * " will be exploded into ['--cron="', '',  '', '', '']
My next option is to write a Split() function to split on long ('--') and short ('-'), but that will break on dash-joined flags (ex: --foo-bar=val). Each element after this explosion could be reconstituted, but this will also encompass bare args.
The second option could be made to work, but the reconstitution is going to be a pain to get right.
In an ideal world, I just call whatever produces os.Arg, but I do not believe that is an option; under the hood this appears to be copying byte sequences provided by the OS (src).

The Go standard library does not have a string split function that follows shell-style rules.  Search for third party libraries.
